# How to stop emacs from contacting melpa?

Tags: use-package, package-repositories

I have the following in  my config:

```lisp
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu"   . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))

(unless (package-installed-p 'org-re-reveal)
  (use-package org-re-reveal
    :ensure t))
```

Why is this still contacting elpa after the second time? I thought the *unless* command  is checking whether this package exist first. What am I assuming wrong?

Comment: The org-reveal package is on Melpa not on Elpa, so you should add the Melpa repo first following the instructions at https://melpa.org/#/getting-started (unless you disabled display of warnings).

Comment: @dalanicolai I have this (see edit).  Does not change anything.

Comment: You are missing the `(package-initialize)` after the `add-to-list`s (see https://melpa.org/#/getting-started). The 'gnu' (elpa) archive is in the list by default, so you don't need that line.